# How to add fullscreen image inside the table

Tags: html, css

I want to add a fullscreen image inside the table, like in the photo bellow

[image]

Comment: At least show a code or something

Comment: Are you using the table for styling purpose or because its holding tabular data? If its for styling, don't use tables. Use a `<div>` and style that.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow :) Please visit [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how to properly ask a question. In order to better assist you, could you provide us with the code you're working with ?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.img_stl {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <span>
    <img class="img_stl" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524419986249-348e8fa6ad4a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80"/> 
    </span>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Let me know what you need extra in it... so I can edit my answer.